# Creating a process dump for Azure App service

Tags: azure, memory, pid, dump, procdump

How can I create a memory dump for an Azure App Service specific process?

I can access the kudu site, but I do not see an option to create a full memory dump for a process that I need to debug.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is more an answer to question no one asked :) Since I couldn't find this info, I decided to share it

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.238744576.1651274397.1655630296-40653997.1640645427

Comment: ok, so I should have posted a question and then an answer to it.. Let me try to edit it and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create a dump file for a specific process of Azure App Service you should go to Kudu site (from the Advanced Tools section) of the Azure App service
Then go to Process Explorer and note the Process Id that you need to create dump for
Then go to Debug Console -> CMD
Navigate to location (create a folder if needed) where the dump will be saved (for example D:\home\data)

Use command to create dump: `d:\devtools\sysinternals\procdump -accepteula -ma <Process ID>`

Once dump is created use Download button next to the file created to download it.